# Macro with \n doesn't work, not sure why.

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I created a macro called `\code` to wrap all the code fragments in my book,

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

But for some reason when I use this `\code{\\n}`, I never get the `\n` displayed. For some reason it turns it into a real new-line and text gets wrapped at that point.

Here is a screenshot that illustrates it. Any ideas what is going on?

[image]

And here is LaTeX code that creates this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
awk '{ print $0 "\n" }'
\end{lstlisting}

This one-liner appends the newline symbol \code{\\n} to the
whole line \code{\$0} and prints it.
```

Answer (score 5):

`\\` is a TeX macro that creates a new line. To typeset a backslash outside a verbatim environment like `lstlisting`, use `\textbackslash`.

Comment: Or use `\lstinline|\n|`

Comment: @Peteris You could make `\n` a macro that writes `\lstinline|\n|` to save yourself some time. I added an answer to this effect...

Answer (score 3):

Since you are writing code, I'd recommend putting it in a verbatim like environment, rather than just `\emph`: use `\lstinline|\n|` to have your `\n` stand out. You can set up listings to have the inline code appear italicised if that's what you want...

Comment: @Peteris No. I don't know how to make inline listings wrap nicely. I guess you'd need to explicitly add hyphenations... No I'm not sure. That's a separate question, really, though...

Comment: It would be an interesting question indeed if it has not yet been asked.